# Checking correctness of the conditional expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Can any one help me verify the following three equations? Do I make any mistake? If yes, can you give me some suggestions? Thank you in advance.

$\mathbb{E} \left ( X^{2} \cdot  Var\left ( Y|X \right ) \right )=\mathbb{E} \left ( X^{2} \right ) \mathbb{E} \left ( Var\left ( Y|X \right ) \right ) $

$\mathbb{E} \left ( X^{2} \cdot  \left [ \mathbb{E} \left ( Y|X \right ) \right ] ^{2} \right )=\mathbb{E} \left ( X^{2} \right )  \mathbb{E} \left ( \left [ \mathbb{E} \left ( Y|X \right ) \right ]^{2} \right )$

$Var\left ( \mathbb{E}\left ( XY|X \right ) \right ) = Var\left (X \cdot 
 \mathbb{E}\left (Y|X \right ) \right )$

Comment: $Var(x\cdot y) \neq Var(x)\cdot Var(y)$, so the second one is incorrect. Google what is the variance of the product.

Comment: Thank you@Andrew

Comment: Since $E[XY\mid X]=XE[Y\mid X]$, the last one is correct. Do you see any reason for the first two to hold?

Comment: $\text{Var}(Y|X)$ and ${\Big(\Bbb E(Y|X)\Big)}^2$ are random variables. You can expect that $\Bbb E(AB) = \Bbb E(A)\Bbb E(B)$ when when $A$ and $B$ are statistically independent, but not in general.

Comment: No, I was think the condition making it independently, but I was wrong @StubbornAtom

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thank you, now I understand. Based on your feedback, can I say E[Y∣X] | X = E[Y∣X] ? So this time it is independent.

Comment: What is independent from what? I'm confused.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Sorry, I made a typo. I mean E{ E[Y∣X] | X } = E[Y∣X], right?

Comment: Do you mean to use the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)? In that case, that would be $\Bbb E(\Bbb E(Y|X)) = \Bbb E(Y)$.

Comment: No, I mean since given condition X, then E[Y|X] is fixed. It means E{ E[Y∣X] | X } = E{ E[Y∣X] | X=x }=E{ E[Y∣X=x] | X=x }=E[Y∣X=x] @Fimpellizieri

Comment: The first equality shold not be true, but I think I get what you're saying.